# 'Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed - Linux Mint

Tags: catkin-make, catkin, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey, I'm getting this error with catkin_make on Linux Mint and haven't really found any actual solution on the internet. It basically happens ever since I've added two repos to my workspace.

```
gil@cheesebacon ~/catkin_ws $ catkin_make
Base path: /home/gil/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/gil/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/gil/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/gil/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/gil/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/gil/catkin_ws/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/gil/catkin_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /home/gil/catkin_ws/devel;/opt/ros/indigo
-- This workspace overlays: /home/gil/catkin_ws/devel;/opt/ros/indigo
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /home/gil/anaconda3/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/gil/catkin_ws/build/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /home/gil/anaconda3/bin/nosetests
-- catkin 0.6.16
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 8 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - neato_2dnav
-- ~~  - neato_driver
-- ~~  - neato_robot (metapackage)
-- ~~  - teleop_twist_keyboard
-- ~~  - exemplo_python
-- ~~  - neato_simulator
-- ~~  - gscam
-- ~~  - neato_node
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'neato_2dnav'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(robotica16/neato_robot/neato_2dnav)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'neato_driver'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(robotica16/neato_robot/neato_driver)
-- +++ processing catkin metapackage: 'neato_robot'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(robotica16/neato_robot/neato_robot)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'teleop_twist_keyboard'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(teleop_twist_keyboard)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'exemplo_python'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(robotica16/exemplo_python)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'neato_simulator'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(robotica16/neato_simulator)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'gscam'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(robotica16/gscam)
-- gst 1.0
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-app-1.0'
--   found gstreamer-app-1.0, version 1.2.4
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'neato_node'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(robotica16/neato_robot/neato_node)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;genlisp;genpy
-- Eigen found (include: /usr/include/eigen3)
-- neato_node: 1 messages, 0 services
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/gil/catkin_ws/build
####
#### Running command: "make -j4 -l4" in "/home/gil/catkin_ws/build"
####
Scanning dependencies of target gscam
Scanning dependencies of target fix_scan_fast
Scanning dependencies of target jpg_stream
Scanning dependencies of target _neato_node_generate_messages_check_deps_Bump
[ 22%] [ 22%] Building CXX object robotica16/neato_robot/neato_node/CMakeFiles/fix_scan_fast.dir/src/fix_scan_fast.cpp.o
Building CXX object robotica16/neato_robot/neato_node/CMakeFiles/jpg_stream.dir/src/jpg_stream.cpp.o
[ 22%] Built target _neato_node_generate_messages_check_deps_Bump
Scanning dependencies of target neato_node_generate_messages_py
[ 33%] Generating Python from MSG neato_node/Bump
[ 44%] Generating Python msg __init__.py for neato_node
[ 44%] Built target neato_node_generate_messages_py
Scanning dependencies of target neato_node_generate_messages_cpp
[ 55%] Generating C++ code from neato_node/Bump.msg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/share/gencpp/cmake/../../../lib/gencpp/gen_cpp.py", line 41, in <module>
    import genmsg.template_tools
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/genmsg/template_tools.py", line 39, in <module>
    import em
ImportError: No module named 'em'
make[2]: *** [/home/gil/catkin_ws/devel/include/neato_node/Bump.h] Error 1
make[1]: *** [robotica16/neato_robot/neato_node/CMakeFiles/neato_node_generate_messages_cpp.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ 66%] Building CXX object robotica16/gscam/CMakeFiles/gscam.dir/src/gscam.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable /home/gil/catkin_ws/devel/lib/neato_node/jpg_stream
Linking CXX shared library /home/gil/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libgscam.so
[ 66%] Built target gscam
[ 66%] Built target jpg_stream
Linking CXX executable /home/gil/catkin_ws/devel/lib/neato_node/fix_scan_fast
[ 66%] Built target fix_scan_fast
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed
```

Also, I've already installed empy, soo the error on "import em" is kinda weird (specially when this line works perfectly fine when I try it on any other python2 file).

Thanks!

PS: I'm using ROS Indigo btw.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228285/%27invoking-%22make--j4--l4%22-failed---linux-mint/) by [pedrocunial](https://answers.ros.org/users/26174/pedrocunial/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-03-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The install instructions probably mention to install `python-empy` which is the Python package not being found in the above output.

**Update:** the CMake output actually shows that `empy` was found. I guess the problem is due to your Python path in combination with you using Anaconda.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2016-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pedrocunial](https://answers.ros.org/users/26174/pedrocunial/) on 2016-03-05**:
Sadly the module was already installed, thanks for the answer tho!

**Comment by [pedrocunial](https://answers.ros.org/users/26174/pedrocunial/) on 2016-03-05**:
Answer for the update: My anaconda is for python 3, after your upgrade I did tried to use `alias python=python2` to change my default python bash environment, but it still didn't work.